# How do I clearRect in my JS canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I may be having a Homer moment here but I am trying to clear the canvas at every iteration to show the square rotating but the clearRect doesn't seem to work.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var angle = 0;
setInterval(function() {
  angle++;

  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  ctx.save();

  ctx.translate(100, 100);
  ctx.rotate(angle);
  ctx.rect(0, 0, 30, 30);
  ctx.stroke();

  ctx.restore();

}, 50);
```

```html
<canvas width='300' height='300' id='myCanvas'></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a `beginPath()` in the code to clear the path. This will cause all rectangles to be redraw each time (and will eventually slow down the whole process).

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var angle = 0;

setInterval(function() {
  angle++;

  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  ctx.save();
  ctx.translate(100, 100);
  ctx.rotate(angle);

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(0, 0, 30, 30);
  ctx.stroke();

  ctx.restore();

}, 50);
```

```html
<canvas width='300' height='300' id='myCanvas'></canvas>
```

Comment: @Jackson no problem. You could also have used strokeRect() to replace beginPath() +  rect().